# Aventail VPN tun0 dropping all packets

Tags: networking, vpn

I'm using Aventail 10.7.1.449 on Ubuntu 14.10 and cannot connect via VPN anywhere, because all packets after the first one are dropped:

```
tun0      Link encap:UNSPEC  HWaddr 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00  
          inet addr:<>  P-t-P:<>  Mask:255.255.255.0
          UP POINTOPOINT RUNNING NOARP MULTICAST  MTU:1452  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:1 errors:0 dropped:190 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:500 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:62 (62.0 B)
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

version 11.4.0.323 seems to have this issue resolved.